# Uncaught ReferenceError (not defined) when checking === undefined

Tags: javascript, comparison, undefined, comparison-operators

I have the following code:

`simpleExample.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Simple example</title>
</head>
<body>
    Open the Console.
    <script src="js/simpleExampleJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`js/simpleExampleJS.js`:

```
MyObject = {
    COMPUTER_GREETING: "Hello World!",
    hello: function() {
        console.log(MyObject.COMPUTER_GREETING);
    }
};

checkSomeGlobal = function() {
    if(someGlobal === undefined) {
        console.log("someGlobal is undefined & handled without an error.");
    } else {
        console.log("someGlobal is defined.");
    }
};

MyObject.hello();
checkSomeGlobal();
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Hello World!
Uncaught ReferenceError: someGlobal is not defined
at checkSomeGlobal (simpleExampleJS.js:9)
at simpleExampleJS.js:17
```

(The first line of output generally indicates that the code is loading and running).

MDN [indicates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) that a potentially undefined variable can be used as the left-hand-size of a strict equal/non-equal [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison).  Yet **when checking** `if(someGlobal === undefined)` that line of code produces an **error** because the variable is undefined, instead of making the comparison evaluate to `true`.  How can I check for and handle this undefined variable case without an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error is saying that there is no such variable (it was never declared), not that its value is `undefined`.

To check whether a variable exists, you can write `typeof someGlobal`, as in:

```
if (typeof someGlobal === "undefined")
```